# Selenium deal with equal elements

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation, html

I am trying to do a progogram that connects to a website, and clicks all the buttons on it. The problem is that the buttons are "equal", and by equal I mean with the same text in them, same link and same css.

Consider the following structure:

```
<content>
<line1>
    <block1> some text </block1>
    <button> Start! </button>
<line2>
    <block2> some different text </block2>
    <button> Start! </button>
<line3>
    <block3> some text different than 1 and 2 </block3>
    <button> Start! </button>
```

How could I make a function to click all buttons? I already tried finding all them with xpath, but once I have them in a list I cannot click them because I can't set a proper wait, so nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all the buttons with same attribute to a list and iterate the list.I tried this it worked perfectly for me.

```
List buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[text()='button text']"));

        for(int i=0;i<=buttons.size();i++){

        ((WebElement) buttons.get(i)).click();

        }
```

pls tell me if its working for you...

Answer (score 0):

try to use the following: 
1) create list; put all the buttons there, iterate through the list clicking on each element (i.e  button).

```
        List <WebElement> buttonList=  
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button"));
        for(int i=0; i<buttonList.size(); i++)
       {
          buttonList.get(i).click();
        }
```

Hope this helps you.